# I want to know how to handle POST requests in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, http-post

Okay, so I want an application to send a POST request to my server at port 8080 or 80. I don't know how to make Node handle these requests. I want to be able to print out the body of the request into the Console.

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) This question is far too broad and open-ended for SO's Q&A format. Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: This projects may help: [Express](https://expressjs.com/), [Koa](https://koajs.com/). The former is the most popular library for handling this stuff in Node.js (for now, these things change).

Comment: any other requirements? like type of content sent? headers? etc.

Comment: Question is too generic, please add example based questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a http server as following and check the request method.
Take a look at [Nodejs Http Server](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_http.asp)

For the anatomy of  [http transactions](https://nodejs.org/es/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/)

And you can use [express](https://expressjs.com/) for handling these ops

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

if (req.method == 'POST') {
    let body = [];
    req.on('data', (chunk) => {
      body.push(chunk);
    }).on('end', () => {
       body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
       // at this point, `body` has the entire request body stored in it as a string
      console.log(body);
    }); 
}

}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

//Create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

app.post('/user', urlencodedParser, function(req,res) {
        console.log(req.body.login);
        console.log(req.body.password);
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Where **login** and **password** are the names of the inputs I get from the form